# Fragment Support Fragment Manager does not exist in current context

Tags: android, android-viewpager, xamarin, fragmentpageradapter, fragmentmanager

In Xamarin, how can I get the `getSupportFragmentManager()` for my own `FragmentPagerAdapter`?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) FindViewById(Resource.Id.viewPager);
        pager.Adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }
}
```

This is the error that I am getting:

> Error CS0103: The name 'getSupportFragmentManager' does not exist in
>   the current context

Can I please have some help to get this working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use method getSupportFragmentManager on Xamarin as it doesn't exist there at all, there is already a property SupportFragmentManager, so just use that one